# Reading email body using gmail in R

Tags: r, gmail

I´m using the gmailr package to send and receive mails from gmail.

I can´t find the way to read the body text of mails in R.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use body() method

> body Get the body text of a message or draft Description Get the body
>   text of a message or draft Usage body(x, ...) Arguments x the object
>   from which to retrieve the body ... other parameters passed to methods
>   Examples

```
## Not run: 
body(my_message)
body(my_draft)
## End(Not run)
```

Comment: `body()` is deprecated as of gmailr 1.0.0.
Please use `gm_body()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to do that,

```
message("INSERT MESSAGE ID HERE")
```

This lets you access the body text(in addition to the details) of the email. As for finding the id of the message, you can use the thread/threads function to do so.